# Quick way to resolve merge conflict by taking their file version

Tags: git

Is there any way to expressly resolve a merge conflict by simply accepting the file version from the other branch when merging into the current branch ?  I would like to avoid using the messy `mergetool` because there is one file that is frequently changed and I always want to override my current branch's version of that file with the version from the merging branch, I don't need to look at the line level diffs to reconcile the deltas.

E.g.

```
git merge other_branch
Auto-merging path/frequently_changed.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in path/frequently_changed.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Is there a quick way to just take the conflict file's version from *other_branch*, assuming it is okay for it to overwrite the current branch's version of the same file?

Comment: You can use the commando `git merge -X theirs branch`
See more in the official [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Comment: Have you tried [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies)?

Comment: @EduardoHitek, does that allow me file-level specificity ?

Comment: @zaratustra: Post that answer as an answer. :)

Comment: @zaratustra, i have not.  how would i do this particular operation using it ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this approach:

```
$ git checkout mybranch
$ git merge --no-commit theirbranch
$ git reset theirbranch -- messyfile
$ git checkout messyfile
$ git commit
```

The problem with trying to use a different merge driver or options to a merge driver is that they apply to the entire merge, not just specific files. Unless this is going to happen often, the above approach is probably the simplest and quickest. If you have to do it frequently, then the approach using a custom merge driver and `.gitattributes` explained in one of the other answers might be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the merge driver:

```
git config --local merge.use_their.driver "use_their.sh %A %B"
```

Here you instruct git to run `use_their.sh` with parameters `%A %B` during merging.

`%A` is the current version of the merged file. After the script finishes its work here has to be the final version of the file,

`%B` is the other branche's version of the file.

You might find out more about possible placeholders using [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver)

So you need to make the current version of the file and the verion of the other branch look alike.

Now you need the script. It might look, for example, like this:

```
$ cat use_their.sh
#!/bin/bash
cp $2 $1
```

this script takes two parameters, the first one is the name of the current verion of the file and the second one is the verion that comes from the other branch. Git simply copies the content of the other branch's version of the file into the current version of the file.

Then you need to configure you `gitattributes`. Since the driver is called `use_their`, this name is used:

```
echo "* merge=use_their" >> .gitattributes
```

Here the asterisk is used in order to make all the files with conflicts turn into their versions of the other branch. You might customize it whatever you want, e.g. use different drivers for different types of files, etc.

Two verion of the file `a` is presented: in the `master` branch it contains `ours` and in the `their_branch` branch it contains `their`. Let's see the driver in action:

```
$ git branch
* master
  their_branch
$ cat a
ours
$ git checkout their_branch
Switched to branch 'their_branch'
$ cat a
their
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge their_branch
Auto-merging a
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 a | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ cat a
their
```

As you can see git using the `use_their.sh` script successfully resolved the conflict.

Comment: thanks but this is ridiculously overcomplicated for the simple thing i am truing to achieve.  i wonder why they didn't build in a prepackaged one liner.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try the `git merge-file`, if you want a file level.
[Docs](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging)